# how much tax return I will get as I have stayed 183 days in US

Tags: united-states, taxes

Hi I am working in US on H1B visa. In financial year 2015 i have stayed in US for 183 days. I have paid some ammount as income tax and other with holdings through out the year. Though i have stayed more than 3 days in (as upto 180 days you dont have to pay any tax)states am  I going to get whole of my income tax return back or how is it going to be ??

Comment: *as upto 180 days you dont have to pay any tax* - what gave you that idea?

Answer (score 4):

You're considered US resident for tax purposes, based on the [substantial presence test](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Substantial-Presence-Test). So you'll need to file your annual tax return (form 1040) by April 15, 2016, on which you'll calculate your tax liability.

If your salary withholding covered your liability, any excess will be refunded to you. If your salary withholding was not enough to cover your liability - you'll have to attach payment to your tax return.

How much exactly you liability is going to be depends on many factors, none of which you mentioned in your question, but you can find on-line estimate calculators if you want.